# read multiple dataset SAS datasets and create a data frame for each with same name

Tags: r

I am trying the below function code, but not sure where i am going wrong, here i am trying to read multiple SAS datasets (5 in number) and create a data frame for each with same name, when i do this I see that the datasets are read and converted to tibble but not the data frame to see in the work environment, the entire data frames gets printed in the form console as lists and tibble (screenshot : where i am showing  the last dataset (5th) in the form of a tibble)

calling the vector dats with datasets names

I am using the haven package to read the sas datasets

```r
readsas <- function(x){
  evalx <- eval(quote(x))
 evalx <- read_sas(paste0('E:\\R\\',evalx,'.sas7bdat'))
 evalx <- evalx[,]
return(evalx)
}

map(dats,readsas)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I also tried to add this portion  `evalx <- as.data.frame(evalx)` to  convert the tibble to a data frame, but does not work

Comment: Base R does not have a function called `read_sas`.   What package are you using?

Comment: using the haven package which is part of tidyverse

Comment: If `dats` is a character vector then there is no need for `eval(quote(.))`. And you can assign `names(your_list) <- dats`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question but it to be saved as dataframe not as tibble in a list?

If correct, change the `map()` function to `map_df()` and add an argument to the `.id` eg("source") so that you know which dataframe belongs to which input.

`map()` will also return a list whereas `map_df()` will return a dataframe